# $\int x^2 e^{x^2} dx = \frac{x^2e^{x^2}}2 - \frac{e^{x^2}}2$ is incorrect?

Tags: calculus, integration

My solution is as follows: $$\int x^2 e^{x^2} dx$$

Use integration by parts:

$u = x^2, du = 2xdx$

$dv = e^{x^2} dx, v = \frac{e^{x^2}}2$

$$\int x^2 e^{x^2} dx = uv - \int vdu = \frac{x^2e^{x^2}}2 - \int e^{x^2}xdx  $$

Note that: $$ \int e^{x^2}xdx = \frac{e^{x^2}}2$$

So our final answer is:

$$\int x^2 e^{x^2} dx =  \frac{x^2e^{x^2}}2 - \int e^{x^2}xdx  =\frac{x^2e^{x^2}}2 - \frac{e^{x^2}}{2} $$

However, the ever-realiable https://www.integral-calculator.com/ gives a very different and more complex answer involving some arcane construct called the imaginary error function. Did I go wrong somewhere in my calculation that led me to arrive a wrong answer?

Comment: You can always check by differentiating, but note that $dv= e^{(x^2)}dx$ does not imply $v=\frac {e^{(x^2)}}2$.

Comment: @lulu Yep, I see that now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Why would the following hold?

$$dv = e^{x^2} \implies \int dv = \int e^{x^2} dx = \frac 1 2 e^{x^2} +C$$

I believe that is where your error lies since $\int e^{x^2} dx$ is not expressible in terms of elementary functions. Indeed, consulting [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+e%5E%28x%5E2%29), we see

$$\int e^{x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2} \text{erfi}(x) + C$$

where $\text{erfi}(x)$ denotes the imaginary error function that perplexed you. You can read more on it [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html).

This sort of error with integrating the exponential is a common mistake for beginners. *(I had a brief diatribe here on what the mistake could've been but I realized a few seconds too late even that didn't make sense, so my bad.)*